# What to do with unapplied migrations in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, migration

Currently I have converted my python 2 project into python 3 project & earlier I was using Django version 1.9.13 & now I have updated it to 2.2.6.

Now I am able to run my project in latest version of python and django but when I run my project in cmd I have found that It showing message like `You have 253 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s)...` so I have checked my migrations folder and able to find all migrations files there.

Any idea why I am getting such kind of message here & if it is bug then what should I do to get rid of such problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: ... apply them?

Comment: In new project I am already using same previous database so if I apply them again does this will affect my database ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same database? Django records the migrations in the database, so if it's saying they are unapplied when they previously were applied then it seems like you are using a different db.

Comment: Yes  I am sure I am using the same database here which I have placed in settings file.

Comment: Are you using sqlite? If so have you copied over the db file?

Comment: Postgresql I am using. I am using same database name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to migrate those migrations to your database. This means you have changes in your model classes but they are not applied to the database you are using. To migrate to the database: in CMD

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

In both cases, make sure you are inside your virtualenv (if you have one) and using the right python. For instance, in most cases if you have multiple pythons installed (2 and 3); you might have to use 'python3' in the above commands.

Comment: but I am already using same database which I am using in old database so I think all migration been applied in already in database so Is it advisable to apply migrations again ?

Comment: Are you saying there is no change in the code after the last migration?